# LinkedIn API getting issue for iOS

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I integrated LinkedIn API into my app using following link

https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

First time its loggedin with pretty good when i was integrated that api into my app. After that onwards getting issue as below from LinkedIn API class and its never opening Linkedin loginview due to error of below

```
- (void)showAuthorizationView:(LIALinkedInAuthorizationViewController *)authorizationViewController {
  if (self.presentingViewController == nil)
    self.presentingViewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
  UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authorizationViewController];
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    nc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  }
   [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

issue is in

```
   [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

the error is

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x787db610> on <myViewController: 0x78677de0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**
```

Its very strange, I checked some forums run code in `viewDidAppear` suggested, but in my case I could not run this in `viewDidAppear` because its not my custom class. Could please anyone suggest me how to avoid this issue? Due to this issue, while I am clicking the LinkedIn login button the Loginview not appearing and I am using `XCode6`. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which says you are trying to present your nc from presentingViewController. But problem here is your `presentingViewcontroller` is not in view hierarchy(i.e the instance that is there in the `presentingViewcontroller` is neither presented nor pushed (Not in view at all))